# How to remove strings and special characters from string and show only numbers without comma using regex?

Tags: android, ios, typescript, react-native

In My case I am using react native typescript, I want to get only numbers from group string without comma. How to get it using regex match or replace?

```
 taskname = TASK_XC0.0.0.0.89t_abc_test
 let task = taskname.match( /[0-9]+/g, ''); //0,0,0,0,89
```

Actual output need to get `000089`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let str = "TASK_XC0.0.0.0.89t_abc_test"

console.log(str.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''))
```

Answer (score 0):

use join method to remove comma

```
const taskName = 'TASK_XC0.0.0.0.89t_abc_test'
const task = taskName.match(/[0-9]+/g, '').join('');
```

output: `000089`